# Cant position TextView in ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm having issues positioning a `TextView` on top of another `TextView` in a `ConstraintLayout` without it overlapping the bottom element. I've tried adding `paddingBottom` and `marginBottom` values to the `TextView`, but it does not seem to budge. Any insights?

Expected Rendering

```
+---------------------------------+
|    7/12/2017                    |
|_______ ________________         |
||     | |              |         |
||Image| |  Text Bubble |         |
||_____| |______________|         |
|_________________________________|
```

**Actual Rendering**

[image: overlapping TextViews]

**Layout**

```
     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">
      <CustomComponent.CircleImageView
          android:id="@+id/rec_image_message_profile"
          android:layout_width="36dp"
          android:layout_height="36dp"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/rec_message_body"
          android:background="@drawable/message_bubble_gray"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:maxWidth="240dp"
          android:padding="8dp"
          android:textColor="#39454C"
          android:layout_marginTop="4dp"    
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rec_image_message_profile"
          android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rec_message_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rec_message_body"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you explain what your desired layout should look like?

Comment: Updated with crude text rendering. Essentially the date should be above both the circle image and textview, with whitespace inbetween.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a layout, I think about which views each of my views will depend on, and then start by first laying out the views that don't depend on anything.

It sounds like your timestamp doesn't depend on anything but the parent. Your image depends on the parent and the timestamp. And your bubble depends on the image.

Here's the XML I write with that in mind. Of course you can tweak the margins/paddings as you see fit.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rec_message_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="7/19/2017 11:05 AM"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rec_image_message_profile"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rec_message_time"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/rec_message_time"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rec_message_body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:maxWidth="240dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#39454C"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        android:background="@drawable/oval"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/rec_image_message_profile"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/rec_image_message_profile"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]